# How to customize UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I have `UIAlertView` which holds an `UIImage` and two default buttons `OK` and `Cancel`.

Now i want to customize `UIAlertView's` background color to white color, and need to add my Image and two default buttons.

Comment: I think this will help you. http://code.google.com/p/iphoneappdevhelp/downloads/detail?name=CustomAlert.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont do that, a lot of customization to `UIAlertView` may lead to the rejection of your application, also since you customized it so much, why dont you just create your own `UIView` Subclass, you will be able to customize it as much as you want

Comment: Thanks i will use UIView. and customize it has for my need's

Answer (score 1):

If your needs are that customized, why not just write a new view controller and present it modally? You can have as much customization as you desire without risking rejection from Apple due to your disregarding of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

See if [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) could be of any use.